# v8 closures of promises questions on comment in source code

Tags: javascript, compilation, v8

Was just looking at the v8 compiler specifically the line in promise-all-element-closure.tq : and I came across the lines.

```
    // Promise.allSettled, for each input element, has both a resolve and a
    // reject closure that share an [[AlreadyCalled]] boolean. That is, the
    // input element can only be settled once: after resolve is called, reject
    // returns early, and vice versa. Using {function}'s context as the marker
    // only tracks per-closure instead of per-element. When the second
    // resolve/reject closure is called on the same index, values.object[index]
    // will already exist and will not be the hole value. In that case, return
    // early. Everything up to this point is not yet observable to user code.
    // This is not a problem for Promise.all since Promise.all has a single
    // resolve closure (no reject) per element.
```

This seams like a bug fix.  I don't quite understand how Promise.allSettled would possibly call resolve reject on the same element more then once?  What was the problem?

Comment: A link to the source you were reading where you found this comment would be useful for context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't quite understand how Promise.allSettled would possibly call resolve reject on the same element more then once?

`Promise.allSettled` doesn't call them at all. The code creating and settling the promise does — and can call them more than once. So `Promise.allSettled` just handles that case by returning early from the function you saw that comment in. In the case where it hasn't seen a settlement for the promise at that index, it continues so it can fill the how in the array it's filling in.

Here's an example of a function that either A) calls `reject` once, or B) calls `resolve` at least once (possibly more than once) and also calls `reject`:

```
function findMatchInStream(stream, text) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        stream.on("line", line => {
            if (line.includes(text)) {
                resolve(line);
            }
        });
        stream.on("end", () => reject());
    });
}
```

That code responds to a Node.js-like `line` event by checking the line for the given text and, if it's found, calling `resolve` — even if it's already called `resolve` previously. Similarly, when it reaches the end of the stream, it calls `reject`, even if it's called `resolve` previously. That's okay (though to my mind, poor) because once you've settled the promise, you can't settle it *again*; subsequent calls to `resolve` or `reject` are ignored.

Sadly, I've seen code **just** like this in the wild.

Comment: this makes since thanks definately was confused on what the Promise was doing.